# Windows 8 WinRT - C++ or C++ .NET?

Tags: c++, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I've heard that Windows 8 development will allow XAML/HTML5 + C++ apps, but is it native unmanaged C++ or managed C++ (formerly C++ .NET) ?

Comment: There's no "C++.NET". Please don't add any more fog and confusion to the already [bewilderingly muddled](http://www.stroustrup.com/uk-objections.pdf) jungle of Microsoft C++ derivatives. There is C++/CLI for the current Windowses, and C++/CX for WinRT (Windows 8), but they're quite different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [*Windows Runtime (WinRT)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Runtime) is itself a native unmanaged framework, but can be called from managed .NET languages in easy way (compared to other native libraries and the infamous `P/Invoke`).

But besides using it from managed languages it can also be called from C++/CX. This is a *Microsoft* extension of standard C++ similar to .NET's C++/CLI. But in contrast to the latter it is entirely native unmanaged C++. But it supports some of C++/CLI's extensions, like the `^` operator for "managed-like" pointers. But under the hood those are not actually managed garbage collected pointers, but native reference-counted pointers, similar to say a `std::shared_ptr`. And it also supports .NET-like properties and delegates, I think, as well as partial classes in order to work with *WinRT*'s *XAML* framework.

Besides that you can even use *WinRT* from standard C++ using the so-called *Windows Runtime C++ Template Library (WRL)*, though it is said to be more-cumbersome than with C++/CX and you may not be able to use all features, like easy *XAML* interfacing, not sure about that.

Answer (score 2):

It is unmanaged C++ which you build into WinRT components.  These components can then be referenced by your HTML5 or Win8 .NET apps.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Slugart's good answer, you are able to write unmanaged C++ for WinRT applications (and Java Script) they are also likely that Microsoft will extend this ability to write unmanaged C++ to Windows Phone 8 also (currently not possible) - which will be a major relef to some development teams, including my own.